# Is it possible to view the edit history of a job posting in StackOverflow Careers

Tags: support, jobs

Is there any way to confirm if the job posting was edited after my application was sent?

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, we don't record what you're looking for. All we record is when something was edited, not what the edit contained.

Comment: Can the user see if the job posting was edited?

Comment: @TariqIbrahim Its an admin only function. Is there a specific concern you have with a listing?

Comment: Is it possible to communicate via email or private message somehow. I know stack exchange doesn't support private messaging :(

Comment: Sure! Email me at careers@stackoverflow.com